# how install joomla on the cloud 9 IDE?

Tags: joomla, ide, cloud, cloud9-ide

I cann't install joomla. In stage two "Database" i write into host name "0.0.0.0", but DB could not connect to MySQL. I tried to write 8080 and localhost, but the result is the same. What can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this source](https://community.c9.io/t/setting-up-joomla/1703), 0.0.0.0 is the correct hostname, so that's probably not the source of your problem.

- have you checked that mysql is running?
- maybe there's a problem with your DB username / password? [This page has a simple php](https://community.c9.io/t/setting-up-mysql/1718) script you could create to test if your DB credentials are correct and MySQL is running.  Set the password and database name and see if it connects.

  ```
  $servername = getenv('IP');
  $username = getenv('C9_USER');
  $password = "...";
  $database = "...";
  $dbport = 3306;

  // Create connection
  $db = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database, $dbport);

  // Check connection
  if ($db->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error);
  } 
  echo "Connected successfully (".$db->host_info.")";
  ```

Good luck!